# How to list filenames in a text file in tree view structure using powershell or command prompt like in the image?

Tags: powershell, text, command

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxjru.jpg)I must have found a command to list file names from a folder into a text file that represents a neat tree structure using the command prompt or Powershell (not any other fancy coding because I don't think I would know how to do that) but I cannot recall how to do it.  Please see the attached picture from a text file that I generated some years ago. I need to know how to do it again.  Thank you.

Comment: [tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree)

Comment: Or `Show-Tree` from the PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX), there are few other modules specific to this on the PowerShell gallery. Though I haven't tried them.

Comment: Try something like reading the folder level with if statement and add pip with space

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I have found the way.  It is the tree command in Powershell.

Comment: The tree command works (not show-tree).

Answer (score 1):

Found it!  This works for me using Powershell:
tree c:\DBA /F > c:\DBA\myFolders.txt
If you use this at a command prompt, it will look okay but the text output won't be as expected as running it from Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
get-childitem "c:\filepath" -recurse |select name | out-file "c:\outpath\file.txt" -Append
```

Comment: The get-childitem does not list the items in a tree format for me (with a visual straight line and branches coming all the way down to the last file)